# Shell Script for hourly count of given fields

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have one file which i have to extract some data and then make the hourly report count. Below is the sample input fields which i have to use and get the final report count in csv format. Extracting the details have been done but the hour report is making it complicated. Could you guys please assist me on this.

```
MO,0,20170608230457826
MT,0,20170608220423442
MO,408,20170608223453234
MO,0,20170608224345342
MT,2,20170608227654342
```

Output is required in below format :

```
MO 0 - 1 - 08/06/2017 23:00
MO 0 - 1 - 08/06/2017 22:00
MT 0 - 1 - 08/06/2017 22:00
MO 408 - 1 - 08/06/2017 22:00
MT 2 - 1 - 08/06/2017 22:00
```

Script which i have prepared till now.

Shell Script

```
            da=`date -d "-1 day" +%Y%m%d`
            for i in VOLTE*
            do
                for j in MO MT CF
                do
                cat $i | grep $j | awk -F"," '{print $2","$11","$20}' >> $j.tmp
                    for n in 0 2 408 480 -1001 500
                    do
                    cat $j.tmp | awk -v num="$n" -F"," '{if( $3 == num ) print $0}' >> "$j"_"$n".tmp
                    done
                done
            done
```

Answer (score 0):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -F, '{ match($3, /^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/, a); 
           printf("%s %s - 1 - %02d/%02d/%4d %2d:00\n",$1,$2,a[3],a[2],a[1],a[4]) }' file
```

The output:

```
MO 0 - 1 - 08/06/2017 23:00
MT 0 - 1 - 08/06/2017 22:00
MO 408 - 1 - 08/06/2017 22:00
MO 0 - 1 - 08/06/2017 22:00
MT 2 - 1 - 08/06/2017 22:00
```

---

- `match($3, /^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/, a)` - matching the needed *datetime* parts in the 3rd field. The array `a` will be filled with values of each captured group, so that `a[1]` contains the value of `([0-9]{4})`

Comment: MO 0 - 1 - 08/06/2017 23:00 --> 1 is the total count in that hour, have to do sum of total MO 0 in 23hr

Comment: @RaviMishra, then why do you have the same `1` for multiple `22:00` hours in your "required" output?